# How to build a stand alone exe with resources?

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, exe

I have a WPF app with image resources. When I build the program, there is a directory named "resources" in the bin folder containing my images. If I run the program without the folder, it crashes. How can I embed the resources in the app so it can run stand alone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set the build action of the image files to `Resource`, like shows [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12693661/1136211). The Uri for an image file named `Image.png` would then be this:

```
pack://application:,,,/Resources/Image.png
```

See also the MSDN page [Pack URIs in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx).