# In my WPF application, my loaded PNG logo in image shows at design time but not at run time

Tags: c#, wpf

This is probably something simple that I am missing.
I have a png file which I want to use as the source of a **Image**control in my WPF window.
I added this PNG file by Project Properties > Resources > Add Existing File and first as a linked file( and then as embedded when it didn't work).Then I add the **Source**for the image control in XAML file to this. No code involved, simple clicking.

The annoying problem is that when I am designing the WPF window the image shows. When I run it , it doesnt. Nothing appears.

Update: ADDED XAML CODE BELOW

```
<Window x:Class="Server.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="SERVER" Height="467.91" Width="620.522">

        <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF080C59" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Button x:Name="btnConnect" Content="Connect" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="425,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="134" Click="btnConnect_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnDisconnect" Content="Disconnect" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" Margin="425,69,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="134" Click="btnDisconnect_Click"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtLog" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="416,160,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="161" Width="87" Background="#FFFFF5F5" Text="LOG:"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtMsg" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="416,326,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="112"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnSend" Content="Send" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" Margin="425,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="134" Click="btnSend_Click"/>
        <ListView x:Name="lsvClients" Height="67" Margin="46,212,260,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="31,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/images/ServerMainLogo.png"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What am I missing?
thanks

Comment: Can you show your `XAML` code?

Comment: In your output folder, can you check if `/images/ServerMainLogo.png` is available?

Comment: @jacobaloysious no its not there , i just checked....

Comment: @iAteABug_And_iLiked_it: Try setting the Properties of the image file  `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy Always`,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you specify the image URI in XAML, it is usually not necessary to write the full URI. Besides the full Pack URI shown in the other answer, you should also be able to write this:

```
<Image ... Source="images/ServerMainLogo.png"/>
```

However, you have to make sure that the image file is located in a folder named `images` in your Visual Studio project and that its [Build Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66.aspx) is set to `Resource`, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12693661/1136211).

Alternatively you could set the *Build Action* to `Content` and *Copy To
Output Directory* to `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`. In this case the image is not embedded as resource into your program's assembly, but simply copied to a directory relative to the executable file.

The (relative) image URI in XAML would work in both cases.

Comment: Yayyyyyyy! it works. I had to first copy the png to the resources folder, then add it in resources too, then it showed up... YIPPPPI!

Comment: Don't copy the file to another folder! If the URI is `images/...` (without leading slash) the file has to be in a folder named "images". That's all.

Comment: I changed my pngs to embedded resource, the designer window was fine with it, the application at runtime not so much.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic It should be Resource, not Embedded Resource.

Answer (score 4):

`siteOfOrigin` should be used only in case your file is copied at place where your other`executables` (Output folder) resides. For Resources you should use `application` instead.

```
Source="pack://application:,,,/images/ServerMainLogo.png"
```

Refer to this link for further clarification [Pack URIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

- Make sure the image properties in the project has "Build Action" =
  "Resource", NOT "Embedded Resource"
- In the xaml, with the image tag selected, use the properties windows to select the Source dropdown since NOW the image appears in the dropdown list! This let visual studio format the string for me. The string visual studio formatted

  for my image was:

  `Source="pack://application:,,,/FamilyExplorer;component/Resources/Folder.png"/>`

Where `FamilyExplorer` was my project name and `Resources/Folder.png` is the location of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution and checks:

- Check your image build action. It should have "Resource" status or option.
- Check your DLL Culture and Resource Culture.
- Set the NeutralResourcesLanguage to "en" like:

```cs
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")] 
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en")]
```