# Image is not displaying in WPF Application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to display an image in wpf application but the image is not displaying in my application, someone give solution for this..

```
 <Image Source="Images/LoadTestInfo.png" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="center" Width="1024" Height="700"  VerticalAlignment="center"  />
```

Thanks in Advance...

Regards

R.Karthik

Comment: you need to set the image as resource and put the complete path

Comment: Have you set the build action property of the image to 'Content'? And in the build folder, does the folder 'images' exist and is the image file in it?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15653339/1136211).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Build Action as Content and select Copy if newer.

Comment: Better set the Build Action to `Resource`, and do not copy do output directory.

Comment: Build Action by default set as Page,                                  If I set to Resource, it showing error Error "The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Can i know for what we are setting Build Action

Comment: After right clicking the image in the folder and setting Build Action to Resource, its working fine

Comment: can u explain me abt purpose of Build Action

Answer (score 0):

Alright, So you need to right click your solution, and ensure that you have added your image. Do this by right clicking then -> add -> new item. Once you have done this, just change the source of you image and it should display the image. Also set build action to resource.