# The background image i set in WPF form doesn't show

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this code:

```
<Window x:Class="wpf_2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowStyle="None" WindowState="Maximized">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="287,147,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
    <Image Source="bg.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"></Image>
</Grid>
```

But when I run the project only the button was shown not the background image.

Comment: Where is placed "bg.png"? It is a resource? A file on disk? Something else?

Comment: I placed it on C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\wpf_2\wpf_2

Comment: You'll have to add the image file to your Visual Studio project (perhaps in a subfolder) and then set its Build Action to `Resource`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12693661/1136211) for example.

Comment: I've created a folder named "Images" in projects folder where the bg.png was located but I cant find the Images folder in the VS solution explorer.

Comment: The folder is not strictly necessary. However, if you want to have one, you'll have to create it in Visual Studio by right-clicking on the project, then select `Add` > `New Folder`.

Comment: So why the bg.png is still not showing in my wpf form? I drag the image from destop to solution explorer I put it under Properties folder and set the Build Action to Resource but still it didnt work.

Comment: Set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy Always` as well.

Comment: Did you then change the XAML to `Source="Properties/bg.png"`?

Comment: @Shoe Not necessary for resource files, as they aren't copied to the output directory

Comment: @AlinaCam Leave `Copy to Output Directory` set to `Do not copy`.