# Not loading image dynamically in wpf

Tags: wpf

Unable to load pictures in WPF window from resource file in separate dll.
It is showing me image at design time but when I run my application, it is not showing me image in my window.
I have tried following:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="/ClassLibrary1;Component/Resources/test.PNG"></Image>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I am setting its Persistence property to "Embedded in .resx" after  I add the file to resource.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12690774/1136211).