# WPF - Import image as resource

Tags: wpf, image

In WinForms it is possible to import an image as a resource, and the image would still work when compiled in the /bin/Debug folder.

I can't figure out how to get this working in WPF, when I run the application the image doesn't load, because the image is saved in `/Projects/AppName/images/`, and the application is compiled into `/Projects/AppName/bin/Debug` when I run it in Debug mode.

Do I simply need to make a copy of my Images folder and put it where the application is compiled? Or is there another way. Here is my code which displays my image:

```
<Image Width="300">
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage DecodePixelWidth="300" UriSource="/images/jamsnaps-dark.png" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 105, accepted):

- Create a folder (e.g. `images`)  in your Visual Studio Project.
- Add the image file(s) to that folder.
- Set their `Build Action` to `Resource` (in the Properties window, see second image in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12693661/1136211)).

Then write the `UriSource` property like you already did:

```
UriSource="/images/jamsnaps-dark.png"
```

That URI is effectively a [Resource File Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly), where the prefix is automatically added by the XAML Parser.

In code behind, you would write

```
bitmap.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/jamsnaps-dark.png");
```

Answer (score 5):

Two options :

1) Go out from bin/Debug and in to your application folder by ../../  and then to your image.

```
  <Image>
      <Image.Source>
           <BitmapImage  UriSource="../../images/jamsnaps-dark.png" />
      </Image.Source>
   </Image>
```

2) Compile your images as Content from properties in the context menu on the image file , and then when compiled they would be placed in been debug.
   I don't remember if you also need to tell them to copy local also in properties ( i'm not near a computer at the moment so i can't check .

Comment: Cheers, also worked but other answered explained a bit better :)

Comment: He did something else .  which is also good .

The point of this is to know where you are locating your files , may they be complied as resources / contents or just placed in your solution . 
i don't remember the pros and cons of each method..

Answer (score 3):

1. Add the image to your project directory
2. In the solutions explorer, right click the image and select `Include in Project`

Build Action should be set to `Resource` by default.

You can then start to use the image path relative to the root e.g. `images/text.jpg` if you put it in a folder called `images`.