# WPF background image

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, background

I was wondering how it would be possible to keep the background image for a wpf form to stay the same when moving from one computer to another. For example in the image source attribute in the XAML file a URL is entered which contains the location of the image. The XAML code looks like this:

ImageSource = "C:\ABC\abc\abc.jpeg"

So when the code is taken to another computer the URL also changes and so the background image is not displayed. So my question is how it would be possible for me to keep the same image without continuously updating the XAML files when I move the code.

Comment: why not just use the image as a resource instead? this way, you wouldn't have to be managing paths, the image will just be part of the application itself.

Comment: Thanks! Like creating a resource dictionary and adding the image as an item to that right?

Comment: Like shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25714375/1136211) (with ImageSource instead od UriSource).

Comment: @Clemens Thanks! Works like a dream