# Relative Resource Uri in WPF Forms

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, relative-path

I'm looking for a method to make all my resource files work properly after I have written my project in a cd.

For example I have saved my images in `Project Name\Project Name\obj\Debug\Images` and I want them to be usable both in xaml and regular c# code, when I insert that cd in another machine.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Whether you write to a CD or Copy to your pendrive or do whatever..
It should work if you have save the image as resource.

Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714085/wpf-import-image-as-resource) and [this](http://wpf.2000things.com/2014/07/03/1107-accessing-an-embedded-resource-using-a-uri/)

Comment: I got it to work in c# but I'm still having trouble in xaml..

Comment: Please post some code.How can somebody figure out what is wrong?
Does it work in the xaml before writing to CD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was, using the Image class for both backgrounds and overlapping images.

In xaml the code is `<Image x:Name="Image1" Source="..\obj\Debug\Images\image.jpg"/>`

and you initialise it in c# using

```
public PageName()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
            Image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"../Images/cafeteria.jpg", UriKind.Relative));                        
        }
```

It's a shame because (atleast in my case) the ImageBrush Class didn't support relative uris for some reason..