# How to set Startup directory to a Image in xaml

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, imagesource

Sorry for bad describe in the title. I have a image in "C:\Users\aUser\Desktop\Program\Image\Image.png" 
But my program is in the same folder with the Image. I can set the Directory manually `<Image Source="C:\Users\aUser\Desktop\Program\Image.png"` But when the parent directory is moved, the code will no longer work. So how can I set the Source of the image that in the child folder without use of the code behind 
`Image.Source = new BitmapSource(new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\Image\Image.png")`
[image]

Comment: I can see that you've updated your question. I'm not sure how you're getting that image (i.e. Logo.png) into the `Resources` folder, so please make sure that you follow [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25714375/510627) to add the image to your project solution and reference it as per my answer

Comment: Anyway, I add Logo.png in code-behind

Answer (score 0):

You will need to be more specific what XAML 'version' you are using (e.g. WPF, UWP or Xamarin.Forms). Anyways, here goes:

**UWP**

You should read [through these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.source#setting-source-in-xaml). Your XAML code could look like this:

```
<Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Image.png"/>
```

Where `Assets/Image.png` is a path to your image

**Xamarin.Forms**

Have a look [at these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=vswin#local-images). The solution depends on the platform

**WPF**

Have a look at [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/imaging-overview#displaying-images-in-wpf). Your XAML code could look like this:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="/Images/image.png" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Comment: I mean C# WPF Application

Comment: Btw when I insert your code, Visual Studio Said Blend do not support this file format

Comment: Made changes to my answer. Added WPF solution - have a look if that works for you

Comment: Assume I Need a Image called Logo.png
The directory point to F:\Resources\Logo.png but I need F:\MySolution\MyProject\bin\Debug\Reources\Logo.png. And the Program is In F:\MySolution\MyProject\bin\Debug\

Comment: I don't think I understand. You want to reference an image that is included in your project or an image that is somewhere on the local hard drive?