# Visual Studio Extension Image is good in design mode but it is hidden in runtime

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility

I am creating a Visual Studio extension with a Custom Tool Window (wpf window).

I have a menu:

```
<MenuItem Header="_Function" Name="mn" >
                <MenuItem Name="menuSearch" Click="MenuSearch_Click" Header="Search">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Resources/search.jpg" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Edit" Name="menuSave" Click="MenuSave_Click" >
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Resources/pen.jpg" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
```

Both of the icons are good in design mode:

[image: design mode]

But when I run the project only the first one is working:

[image: Runtime]

I have read this post: [Image not visible in WPF 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241184/image-not-visible-in-wpf-2015)

and both of the images are `Build Action: Resource`. And the last thing i must say is that the second image works if I set a static url:

```
<MenuItem.Icon>
           <Image Source="J:\My_Programs\1397\MyKeywords\MyKeywords\Resources\pen.jpg" />
</MenuItem.Icon>
```

Do you know the solution? Thanks.

**Update**

And this post:

[WPF - Import image as resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714085/wpf-import-image-as-resource)

will not help because one image is working and another not, in a same condition.

Comment: Try these? Embedded Resource? Copy to output always?,

Comment: I suggest you to use a `PackURI` and not a relative/absolute Path. See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf

Comment: @FaisalHafeez I tested both without success.

Comment: @FarzinKanzi See the output folder. Do you images there?,

Comment: Do you mean bin/debug? I saw there and no one of the images are there. I added the pen.jpg there and tested again and there was no changes.

Comment: @LittleBit Thank you, but I have seen that page previously.

Comment: So what happens when you set `<Image ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/search.jpg" />` and the Build Action to `Resource`+ `Do not Copy`?

Comment: @LittleBit I have tested this without success, But it could be true solution! My first Icon also was invisible yesterday and today is working. And as @FaisalHafeez said I set `copy to output` but did not copy! So I restarted the visual studio and It worked.

Comment: @LittleBit You do not have to write a full Pack URI in XAML. `<Image Source="Resources/search.jpg"/>` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in a VSIX project, Some of the changes do not affect until the visual studio restart. I restarted the visual studio and now every things are OK with:

```
Build Action: Resource
Copy To Output Directory: Do Not Copy
```