# Load image from specific file

Tags: c#, wpf, blend

How can I set the ImageSource to be an image from a specific folder?

I tried moving the image in Debug and running the following code:

```
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("kafpodhlato.png"));
```

But I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in
>   System.dll
>
> Additional information: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not
>   be determined.

EDIT: Creating a folder named Resources, setting its `Build action` to `Resource` and then using the following code solved my problem.

```
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Resources/panamaxi.png"));
```

Comment: Maybe using another `Uri` constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("kafpodhlato.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

---

You may however want to load the image from an assembly resource by a [Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx).

Add the image file to your Visual Studio project, e.g. to a folder named `Images`. Then set its `Build Action` to `Resource`, and load it by

```
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/kafpodhlato.png"));
```

Comment: Tried it and no error, but the image won't load... Maybe I have to specify the path better? Or putting the image in Debug solves this problem?

Comment: @ThP See my edit. You should make your image file an assembly resource.

Comment: Can you please explain to me how to set its `Build Action` to `Resource` ? I currently get no properties to change except for it's name.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12693661/1136211. In VS, open the content menu on the file and select Properties.

Comment: Are you sure that you use the correct project folder name in the Pack URI? What about `image`, is it declared in XAML? Are you sure it's visible? There are a lot of things that may be wrong, but we can only guess.