# Casting BitmapImage to Image.Source

Tags: c#, image, xaml, url, bitmapimage

I am currently stuck on a piece of my project in Visual Studio 2017. The following code is meant to set the Source of an Image component on a .xaml page.

```
private void setImage()
    {
        var image = new Image();
        var imageUrl = @"http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/5.2.1/img/" +
        currentChamp.Image.Group + "/" + currentChamp.Image.Full;
        Debug.Write(imageUrl);
        BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage();
        bmi.BeginInit();
        bmi.UriSource = new Uri(imageUrl, UriKind.Absolute);
        bmi.EndInit();

        image.Source = bmi;
    }
```

Here is the code to be referenced. ^^^

In all other questions I have found **similar** to what I am asking, this has unanimously been the correct/answered/approved way of doing what I am trying to do. However, I am receiving an error that **no one** else has received in any of the question

*cannot implicitly convert system.windows.media.imaging.BitmapImage to Windows.UI.XAML.media.ImageSource*

My imports, references, and types have all been checked and are correct. Am I missing a framework? Was there an update that may have caused this to no longer work?

I am using VS2017 working in Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform

Note that this is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690774/assign-bitmapimage-from-resources-resx-to-image-source), as I am not referencing a resource folder and my path is Absolute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage` is a WPF class. `Windows.UI.XAML.media.ImageSource` is UWP. You found solutions for WPF, but your UWP `Image` class wants a UWP bitmap object. You need something using [`Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage).

I'm unable to test UWP at the moment, but from reading the documentation, I think you want something like this:

```
image.Source = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(imageUrl, UriKind.Absolute));
```

It appears that you have `using Windows.Media.Imaging;` in your C# file. It would be wise to replace that with `using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;`

Then you could just use this:

```
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageUrl, UriKind.Absolute));
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, as did your example. Thank you very much, I would've never caught that. I am relatively new to c# and debugging has been my biggest challenge.

Answer (score 2):

The error message here tells you exactly what is wrong.  You are using a non-UWP `BitmapImage` in a UWP project.  Get rid of your using for `System.Windows.Media.Imaging` and change it to `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging`.