# Images in ListView in WPF app with databinding

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to add an image to my `ItemTemplate` in `ListViewm` however, I am not getting past the "address" of the image by `databinding`.
I can display the names perfectly, only the images that does not.
How can I pass the name of the image to `ImageBrush`and not to `Image.Source`

Here is my code in C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        List<User> items = new List<User>();
        items.Add(new User() { BitmapImage = "default-user-image.png", Name = "John Doe"});
        items.Add(new User() { BitmapImage = "default-user-image.png", Name = "Jane Doe"});
        items.Add(new User() { BitmapImage = "default-user-image.png", Name = "Sammy Doe"});
        lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = items;
    }
}

public class User
{
    public string BitmapImage { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string Mail { get; set; }
}
```

As it can be observed, I have a `User` object, and the `BitmapImage` as `String`.

And here's my XAML code, which gets the items from the list:

```
<ListView Name="lvDataBinding" Grid.Column="0">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Ellipse Width="40" Height="40">
                            <Ellipse.Fill>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding BitmapImage}"/>
                            </Ellipse.Fill>
                        </Ellipse>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Where are the images located? Are the images resources of your executable?

Comment: Make sure the images have a **Build Action** of either **Resource** or **Content** in the VS 'Properties' pane.  If they're located in a folder (or sub-folder), specify the full relative path in your image URI.

Comment: Set the Build Action to Resource and use a Pack URI: `pack://application:,,,/default-user-image.png`.

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg Putting the full path of the image worked properly, how could I put it to work in whatever folder it is running? (I'll edit the question)

Comment: @Clemens like this: `BitmapImage = "pack://application:,,,/default-user-image.png"` ?

Comment: That should work.

Comment: @Clemens Unfortunately it didn't work, any other suggestions?

Comment: Is the image file part of your Visual Studio project, and did you set its Build Action?

Comment: @Clemens No... it's works if I put the full path of the image. How can I set its Build Action?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12693661/1136211

Comment: @Clemens Its works fine! thank you!!