# WPF UserControl with Image Property

Tags: wpf, image, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have a UserControl Library containing a user control to make a custom title bar for windows. I have given this title bar two dependency properties - Title and Icon, which I would like to be able to set when I use the control through a DLL.

I have got the title working correctly, so that when I set a Title property of the Window's ViewModel, it is populated into the title bar. However, I cannot get the image to do the same.

I have tried all sorts of variations, and read an entire course on using dependency properties, but I just can't seem to get the image to show. I have tried using ImageSource properties, Project Resources, and Images, but all I get is a blank. Can you point me in the right direction to fix the issue?

Here is the xaml for the usercontrol (I Read that I had to use the TemplatedParent RelativeSource for the DP, so that is put in - I believe that this will refer to the MainViewModel in the implementation):

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFLibrary.User_Controls.TitleBar"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WPFLibrary;component/Styles/Buttons.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WPFLibrary;component/Styles/Gradients.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WPFLibrary;component/Styles/Text.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
               MouseDown="TitleBar_MouseDown"
               DataContext="{Binding}"
               Background="{StaticResource WindowTitleBar}">
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding Icon,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Title_Bar"
                       Grid.Column="3"
                       Text="{Binding Title}"
                       Style="{StaticResource Text_WindowTitle}">
            </TextBlock>
            <!--StackPanel Containing the buttons excluded for SO Question-->
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

and here is the code behind for the same control (Following from some other SO answers, I have tried using project resources and ImageSource for the Image property, but to no avail):

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WPFLibrary.User_Controls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for TitleBar.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class TitleBar : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public Image Icon
        {
            get { return (Image)GetValue(IconProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Icon.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", typeof(Image), typeof(TitleBar) );

        private static PropertyChangedEventArgs _stateChange = new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Windowstate");
        public WindowState _windowState;

        public WindowState Windowstate
        {
            get
            { return _windowState; }
            set
            {
                _windowState = value;
                NotifyChange(_stateChange);
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyChange(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
        }

        public TitleBar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Button Click Methods excluded for SO question
    }
}
```

The xaml for the implementation of the usercontrol is like this - I set the binding to the MainViewModel; that has a constructor that sets the properties.

```
<Window x:Class="Demo_of_WPF_Library.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:WPFLibrary.User_Controls;assembly=WPFLibrary"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Demo_of_WPF_Library.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowStyle="None"
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
        x:Name="Main_Window"
        WindowState="{Binding Windowstate,ElementName=Titlebar}"
        Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
        Height="300" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainView_Model/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <uc:TitleBar Name="Titlebar" Icon="{Binding Icon}">
        </uc:TitleBar>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is the code for the MainView_Model that holds the properties for the mainwindow:

```
namespace Demo_of_WPF_Library.ViewModel
{
    public class MainView_Model
    {
        private string _title;
        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set { _title = value; }
        }
        private Image _icon;

        public Image Icon
        {
            get { return _icon; }
            set { _icon = value; }
        }

        public MainView_Model()
        {
            Title = "Demo WPF Library";
            Icon = new Image();
            Icon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/View/Images/IsItOk.ico",UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, here is the code behind the mainwindow, which sets the binding to the MainViewModel and initialises the window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainView_Model MainView { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        MainView = new MainView_Model();
        DataContext = MainView;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I honestly cannot see what it is that is missing / wrong here and I have read loads of articles, questions and answers that basically seem to say that I'm doing things in the correct way... So what on earth is wrong?

Comment: I"m probably missing where you actually set the Icon property. ALSO depending where then you're MainView_Model class needs to implement INofityPropertyChanged  I see it now. When you step through it, is Icon.Source set?

Comment: I thought I was setting the Icon property In the constructor for the mainView_model... setting the Icon.Source is not setting the image? I added in the INotifyPropertyChange implementation, but that has not solved the issue.

Comment: Did you step through and ensure that .Source is set? Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12693661/3225

Comment: `.Source` is set, although all other properties are default or empty. The Image is a `System.Windows.Controls.Image`, by the way, not a `System.Drawing.Image`. This caused me a deal of angst, so I figured I would mention!

Comment: I read a different SO answer and set the build action to `Component`! I have tried both ways and neither solves the issue.

Comment: I think the new Image() probably requires arguments, likely that's the way to pass in the image path which might set all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you've got an Image in your XAML which is trying to bind to an Image in your view model. GUI objects like `Image` have no place in your view model layer, change your `Icon` dependency property to be of type `ImageSource` and bind your XAML image to that instead.

Comment: I'm not certain I understand exactly how to implement that - I changed the type of the DP in the UserControl to ImageSource and the same in the view model, setting the source using a BitmapImage as before, but that did not work. I also added an image to the xaml as a static resource and bound the new ImageSource  DP to that, but it also failed. I'm sorry, I think I have got myself considerably muddled. Could you give a little more detail, please?

Comment: I've tried some more things and now I am certain I don't understand how to implement what you describe correctly

Comment: Got it! Combined with @Rekshino 's answer, this solved it - I put the reference in MainWindow.xaml.cs, instead of the view model and used it to directly set `Titlebar.Icon = bitmap`. I wish I could mark two responses as the answer!

Answer (score 4):

Your binding is wrong. You shouldn't use a `TemplatedParent` if you have no template. Use:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFLibrary.User_Controls"
<Image Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding Icon, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:TitleBar}}"/>
```

Comment: This, combined with @Mark Feldman 's answer has solved it. I wish I could mark two responses as the answer!

Comment: @HighPlainsGrifter well spotted, I didn't notice that one.